# How to limit depths structures in prolog

Tags: prolog

I trying to write a grammar that generates expresions. If I do not set a depth limit the recursion goes throw the last variable and be infinity. I do not know how to limit depth branching the tree recursion.

I try this:

```pl
constant('c1').
variable('v1').
operator('+').

expresion(C) :- constant(C).
expresion(V) :- variable(V).
expresion(bin(E1,O,E2)) :- 
    expresion(E1), 
    operator(O), 
    expresion(E2).

expresionL(C, 0) :- constant(C).
expresionL(V, 0) :- variable(V).
expresionL(bin(E1,O,E2), N) :- 
    N_1 is N-1, 
    expresionL(E1, N_1), 
    operator(O), 
    expresionL(E2, N_1).
```

Here is a [live online version](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/simple-grammar.pl).

If I query `Expresion(X)` y obtain:

```
X = c1
X = v1
X = bin(c1, (+), c1)
X = bin(c1, (+), v1)
X = bin(c1, (+), bin(c1, (+), c1))
X = bin(c1, (+), bin(c1, (+), v1))
X = bin(c1, (+), bin(c1, (+), bin(c1, (+), c1)))
```

...to infiniy and beyond! (recursing over the las expresion). I never see `v1`.

I write `expresionL` to be a depth limited version of expression.

If I query `expresion(bin('v1','+','c1')).` or query `expresion(bin('v1','+','c1')).` I get `true`.

If I query `expresionL(X,1).` I get:

```
X = bin(c1, (+), c1)
X = bin(c1, (+), v1)
Stack limit (0.2Gb) exceeded
  Stack sizes: local: 0.2Gb, global: 51.1Mb, trail: 1Kb
  Stack depth: 1,673,655, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 13
  Possible non-terminating recursion:
    [1,673,655] expresionL(_1404, -1673622)
    [1,673,654] expresionL(<compound bin/3>, -1673621)
```

I do not see `v1` in the first parameter of `bin` of any answers. The inifite recursion does not stops.

### How can I write a `expresion(E, N)` version that limit recursion to N steps?

Notes:

- I know that my tried version computes exact N levels of depth and I want `<= N levels`
- This results are of the online version. In my computer I get the same results but with other amount of memory consumed.

Comment: Why not write a grammar? That is a [tag:dcg]?

Comment: @false, suggestions are welcome. I was 30 years without writing prolog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you allow the expression to be evaluated recursively even if `N <= 0`, because while backtracking, the last rule is a viable option even if N becomes zero or even less. You need to rule that out in the last rule using `N > 0`.

Adding that to the code:

```
expresionL(C, 0) :- constant(C).
expresionL(V, 0) :- variable(V).
expresionL(bin(E1,O,E2), N) :- 
    N > 0, # select this rule only when the others fail
    N_1 is N-1, 
    expresionL(E1, N_1), 
    operator(O), 
    expresionL(E2, N_1).
```

results in:

```
?- expresionL(X,1).
X = bin(c1, +, c1) ;
X = bin(c1, +, v1) ;
X = bin(v1, +, c1) ;
X = bin(v1, +, v1) ;
false.
```

Comment: Here I post the final solution with your suggestion and `expresion(E,N):-N>0,expresion(E,0)` to achieve `N>0`: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/simple-grammar-ok.pl